# Dockerfile parse error line 7: COPY requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided. Destination could not be determined

Tags: dockerfile

Docker file content: Error - Dockerfile parse error line 7: COPY requires at least two arguments, but only one was provided. Destination could not be determined

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app

WORKDIR /home/node/app

COPY package*.json ./

USER node

RUN npm install

COPY --chown=node:node . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The full, proper way to do it is:

```
COPY --chown=node:node . ./
```

That is because `COPY` expects 2 arguments (as the error message says), it just doesn't like the second bare dot.

Answer (score 1):

```
COPY --chown=node:node ./  --> just try this, it should work.
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score 1):

I was forgetting to include a dot after `COPY package.json` in my Dockerfile.

My full working Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json . 

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

adding app.jar in suffix worked for me

COPY target/com.me.xxxxx-1.0.0.jar app.jar

Answer (score -3):

On line 7 - `COPY --chown=node:node . .` Both source and destination are the same which is invalid.

The source and destination should be different.